# view in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

In android studio while creating a button , I am using a function name in onclick attribute to invoke a code execution

example : onClick : myButton

public void myButton (View a)

1) what is meant by view in the above command ?
2) why they are specifing view in the function that is related to Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) what is meant by view in the above command ?

The view that is calling that function.

> 2) why they are specifing view in the function that is related to Button?

Because you could call that function from different views (like layouts or textviews), not just buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the answers of your questions

1) what is meant by view in the above command ?

Here is View is the view that is clicked, and in future you with this view reference you can perform many actions or you can play with the state of the view according to your need.

2) why they are specifying view in the function that is related to Button?

This is polymorphic way of representing. Button is a child of View. If you have parent access, you can achieve polymorphism easily and further you can get specific behaviour that belongs to Button as well via casting.

Hope this will help you.